# How to implement dynamic table <tbody></tbody> and populate data into datatable using API ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp

I am new to jquery and javascript. I want to populate my datatable using Ajax call. I am trying to create a table body dynamically in spring mvc. I have done pagination part through API. I want to populate my datatable using API too. I don't know where I am doing things wrong. So, please find the code below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "api/getusertable"; 
        alert(url);
        $.post(url,{ 
            
        }, function(data, status) { 
            if (data.status == "OK") { 
                if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                    
                    var row = "";  //Variable to hold html tag 
                    var list = data.response;
                    var listlength = list.length;
                    for( var i = 1; i < listlength; i++)
                        {
                              row = row+"<tr id='tr"+user.userid+"' onclick=\"selectedrow('"+user.userid+"');\">"
                              +"<td>"+user.company+"</td>"+"<td>"+user.companystatus+"</td>"+"<td>"+user.phone+"</td>"
                              +"<td>"+user.address+"</td>"+"<td>"+user.landline+"</td>"+"</tr>";
                        }
                    document.getElementById('tablebody').innerHTML = row;
            } else {
                     var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            } else {
                     var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
            }
        });
        
    });
    </script>
```

This is all about the code.

Comment: At first, why you are using `post` method to get data? It's not standard!

Comment: Also, I didn't understand your exact question! But I correct a mistake that you done: Instead of using `innerHTML`, use the jQuery function to append rows: `$('#tablebody').append(row);`.

Comment: To handle type : post method, I have used method for both get or post type of request in my controller. @RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.getusertable, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }

Comment: Did the `append` function solve your issue?

Comment: innerHTML worked on that. Thank you.